# WinrtXamlToolkit TreeView ItemContainerStyleSelector not firing

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am using the [TreeView](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/tree/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/TreeView) control from the [WinrtXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit) in a uwp app. I want to apply a different style to some TreeViewItems depending on a conditon so I created a class, TreeViewItemStyleSelector which derives from StyleSelector and I override the SelectStyleCore function.

```
 public Style ResourceStyle { get; set; }

 public Style ClassroomStyle { get; set; }

 protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            // control never reaches here. 
            // logic to apply style
        }
```

Then in xaml I use it like this.

In Page Resources

```
<StyleSelectors:TreeViewItemStyleSelector ResourceStyle="{StaticResource AStyle}" ClassroomStyle = "{StaticResource BStyle}"/>
```

And later in the page.

```
<wxtControls:TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding StructureViewModels}" ItemContainterStyleSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyleSelector}" />
```

The problem is that the SelectStyleCore override is never called. Does anybody know why?

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. But couldn't found an solution to this. I have posted an issue in WinRTXamlToolKit's Github. Let's wait for the response.:)

Comment: The response comes late and is incomplete, but it's a response... :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not yet sure what's the reason this doesn't work, although I have some theories. One is - this was never implemented. Perhaps at least at the root level it should work because it's an `ItemsControl`, but because of the way it's implemented (hierarchically) - the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` would have to be forwarded from the `TreeView` to the `TreeViewItems`, which it isn't.

I haven't had a chance to try to reproduce it yet, but if I were to try to fix it or work around it - I would first try forwarding that property in `HeaderedItemsControl.cs` - roughly where it says "`// Note: this is where we would apply the HeaderTemplateSelector (...) (if implemented)`". The alternative (if you don't want to modify the toolkit's code) might be to specify the template for the `TreeViewItem` and in the template - use a `StyleSelector` on template parts you want to be different for different data items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already went for option 2 along with tampering with the style of the TreeViewItem. Thanks again for taking time to look at this and for an awesome toolkit :)